# The -d database name option is not supported when a 3 part dbtable name is specified

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, dataframe, bcp

I'm trying to insert data from Python DataFrame to SQL Server table. I can do that using Pyodbc.  But, when I'm trying to use to_sql from bcpandas library,the code is failing if I provide the SchemaName.TableName.

The table name is dbo.BCPTest. If I do not specify the SchemaName, the DataFrame is being inserted into the table and the code is executing successfully, but my point is, I'm not supposed to use the dbo schema in the real time scenarios.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from bcpandas import SqlCreds, to_sql

creds = SqlCreds(
'DEV_SERVER',
'DEV_DB',
'SQLServer_UserName',
 'SQLServer_Password'
   )

df = pd.DataFrame(
   data=np.ndarray(shape=(10, 6), dtype=int),
   columns=[f"col_{x}" for x in range(6)]
   )

#print(df)   
try:

    to_sql(df, 'BCPTest', creds, index=False, if_exists='replace')

except Exception as E:
    print(E)
```

Now, my SQL Server table is under dbo schema that is why the code is executing successfully if I do not specify the Schema Name. My question is, how and where to specify the table schema name in the above code?

Comment: Adding the scheme makes 2-part naming, your error says 3 part naming, which suggests you are using the database name as well?

Comment: When I'm providing the Schema Name in the below expression, then only it is giving the above error. I'm not specifying the database name. I've tried, dbo.BCPTest and [dbo].[BCPTes], both are giving the same error.
to_sql(df, 'dbo.BCPTest', creds, index=False, if_exists='replace')

Comment: The error message would give most SQL Server DBAs a clue about what's going on: `bcpandas` is just a wrapper around the `bcp.exe` utility. Its `to_sql` method exports the dataframe to a .csv file and then uses the `bcp.exe` utility to read that data into the target SQL Server table. Instead of specifying `table_name='dbo.BCPTest'` you should instead use `table_name='BCPTest', schema='dbo'`. The `schema` parameter defaults to `dbo`, so using it like you are causes it to generate the target table name on the bcp command line as `dbo.dbo.BCPTest`, which is a three part name.